# After call epoll_wait() Linux system is returning Interrupted system call (error no 4)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, call

This is occurring when going to process more than 300 UDP socket. The code retry by calling 
epoll_wait(). But again returning error no 4.

Comment: It'll do that if your program gets a signal delivered while it's waiting. Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes. I have one. How i can resolve this ?

Comment: By either blocking the signal(s) that are interrupting your calls, or by writing your code to take into account the fact that certain calls may be interrupted by signals. Hard to say what approach you should take, since nothing is known about your application...

Comment: @SohagMony We first need to know whether there is a problem to resolve. Getting EINTR if a signal arrives while blocked in epoll_wait() is expected. One way to deal with that is to retry the epoll_wait() which you say you do.